# Python pandas - преобразовать часть "верхнего" мультииндекса в столбец

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

имеем датафрейм с мультииндексом в части столбцов

```
pd.DataFrame(
data=np.array([[31. , 38.7, 32. , 36.7],
            [44. , 37.7, 50. , 35. ]]),
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bob', 'Guido'], ['HR', 'Temp']], names=['Name', 'Indicator']))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

имеется ли простой способ выполнить такое преобразование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: воспроизводимый пример исходных данных должен быть приведен в вопросе.

Comment: @strawdog Done.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вам поможет метод stack с указанием имени (или порядка) индекса:

```
res = df.stack(level="Name")
```

res:

```
Indicator    HR  Temp
  Name               
0 Bob      31.0  38.7
  Guido    32.0  36.7
1 Bob      44.0  37.7
  Guido    50.0  35.0
```